# Is it possible to disable sorting for particular column with customfields in React Admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have a custom field for user status but I want to disable the default sorting on that column.

like when we use predefined fields like

Comment: Please share some so that we can have clear understanding what you need.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to disable sorting for a specific field by passing a sortable property set to false: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#disabling-sorting

`<TextField source="id" sortable={false} />`

Comment: No, This is for prebuilt TextField component I want disable sorting on my own custom fields.

Comment: LIke I have a custom field "<GenderField />"  I want to disable sorting for this field.

Comment: This should also work for the custom field, have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I have tried this but not able to sort. actually I am using Typescript so getting this error :-   Type '{ sortable: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & FieldProps<User> & { children?: ReactNode; }'.

Comment: I got the answer! Thanks

Comment: This is the right answer. Using Typscript, just you need to add the property "sortable: boolean" to your interface.